# eccentricity of locus of circle

Tags: geometry

A circle cuts two fixed perpendicular lines such that each of the non zero intercept is of given length (but unequal).Now we have to prove the eccentricity of locus of the centre of the circle is $\sqrt2$ .

Comment: What are the two lengths?

Answer (score 0):

Let $(x,y)$ be the centre of the circle.

WLOG, take the two perpendicular lines to be the $X$ and $Y$ axes.

$$y^2+a^2=x^2+b^2$$

Where $a$ and $b$ are the two sub segments(=segment length/2)

Comment: How you have written the equation

Comment: @user123733 Assume $2b$ to be the intercept on the $Y$ axis and $2a$ to be on the $X$ axis. (2 perpendicular lines). Sum of squares =radius$^2$

Comment: Why sum of squares = radius$^2$

Comment: @user123733 If you draw the diagram .you will understand